# Sum with 3 tables to join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum

I have 3 tables. The link between the first and the second table is `REQ_ID` and the link between the second and the third table is `ENC_ID`. There is no direct link between the first and the third table.

INS_RCPT

```
+----+--------+------+----------+
| ID | REQ_ID | CURR | RCPT_AMT |
+----+--------+------+----------+
|  1 |      1 | USD  |      100 |
|  2 |      2 | USD  |      200 |
|  3 |      3 | USD  |      300 |
+----+--------+------+----------+
```

ENC_LOG

```
+----+--------+--------+-------------+
| ID | REQ_ID | ENC_ID | ENC_LOG_AMT |
+----+--------+--------+-------------+
|  1 |      1 |      1 |          20 |
|  2 |      1 |      2 |          50 |
|  3 |      1 |      3 |          30 |
|  4 |      2 |      4 |          20 |
+----+--------+--------+-------------+
```

ENC_RCPT

```
+----+--------+--------------+
| ID | ENC_ID | ENC_RCPT_AMT |
+----+--------+--------------+
|  1 |      1 |           10 |
|  2 |      1 |           10 |
|  3 |      2 |           15 |
|  4 |      2 |           25 |
|  5 |      2 |           10 |
|  6 |      3 |           12 |
|  7 |      3 |           18 |
|  8 |      4 |           10 |
+----+--------+--------------+
```

I would like to have output as follows:

```
+----+--------+------+----------+-------------+--------------+
| ID | REQ_ID | CURR | RCPT_AMT | ENC_LOG_AMT | ENC_RCPT_AMT |
+----+--------+------+----------+-------------+--------------+
|  1 |      1 | USD  |      100 |         100 |          100 |
|  2 |      2 | USD  |      200 |          20 |           10 |
|  3 |      3 | USD  |      300 |           0 |            0 |
+----+--------+------+----------+-------------+--------------+
```

I am using SQL Server to write this query. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where are you having difficulty? Have you looked into using JOINs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to join the first table to two subqueries which compute the sums separately:

```
SELECT
    ir.ID,
    ir.REQ_ID,
    ir.CURR,
    ir.RCPT_AMT,
    el.ENC_LOG_AMT,
    er.ENC_RCPT_AMT
FROM INS_RCPT ir
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT REQ_ID, SUM(ENC_LOG_AMT) AS ENC_LOG_AMT
    FROM ENC_LOG
    GROUP BY REQ_ID
) el
    ON ir.REQ_ID = el.REQ_ID
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.REQ_ID, SUM(t2.ENC_RCPT_AMT) AS ENC_RCPT_AMT
    FROM ENC_LOG t1
    INNER JOIN ENC_RCPT t2 ON t1.ENC_ID = t2.ENC_ID
    GROUP BY t1.REQ_ID
) er
    ON ir.REQ_ID = er.REQ_ID
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Note that your question includes a curve ball.  The second subquery needs to return aggregates of the receipt table by `REQ_ID`, even though this field does not appear in that table.  As a result, we actually need to join `ENC_LOG` to `ENC_RCPT` in that subquery, and then aggregate by `REQ_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query. Also change the join from left to inner as per your requirement.

```
select a.id,a.req_id,a.curr,sum(a.rcpt_amt) rcpt_amt,sum(a.enc_log_amt) enc_log_amt,sum(c.enc_rcpt_amt) enc_rcpt_amt
from
(
select a.id id ,a.req_id req_id ,a.curr curr,sum(rcpt_amt) as rcpt_amt,sum(enc_log_amt) as enc_log_amt
from ins_rcpt a
left join enc_log b
on a.req_id=b.req_id
group by id,req_id,curr
) a
left join enc_rcpt c 
on a.enc_id = c.enc_id
group by id,req_id,curr;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim. Because of the curve ball, I was not able to find solution for it.